# Object(...) is not a function - Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Please help me with this error.

I am trying to apply some styling for the MUI dropdown but I am getting this **Object(...) is not a function** error

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const dropDownStyle = makeStyles({
  formControl: {
    "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
      color: "#6EC177",
      borderColor: "#6EC177",
      borderWidth: "1px",
      borderStyle: "solid",
      borderRadius: "100px",
      minWidth: "120px",
      justifyContent: "center",
    },
    "& .MuiSelect-select.MuiSelect-select": {
      paddingRight: "0px",
    },
  },
  select: {
    width: "auto",
    fontSize: "12px",
    "&:focus": {
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
    },
  },
  selectIcon: {
    position: "relative",
    color: "#6EC177",
    fontSize: "14px",
  },
  paper: {
    borderRadius: 12,
    marginTop: 8,
  },
  list: {
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    "& li": {
      fontWeight: 200,
      paddingTop: 8,
      paddingBottom: 8,
      fontSize: "12px",
    },
    "& li.Mui-selected": {
      color: "white",
      background: "#6EC177",
    },
    "& li.Mui-selected:hover": {
      background: "#6EC177",
    },
  },
});

export default dropDownStyle;`
```

**Object(...) is not a function****Object(...) is not a function****Object(...) is not a function**

Error:

[image]

MUI and React version

[image]

Comment: Have you installed using `npm install @material-ui/core` ?

Comment: Yes I have installed using npm install @material-ui/core

Comment: isn't @material-ui old version. The latest version is @mui/material

Comment: How do you use `dropDownStyle`?